When you attempt to send SOLto an address that doesn't yet exist on the network,what will happen?
the network will automatically create the account for that address when it receives the tokens.is that right?who will affort to create the receiver address account?

One of two things:

If you send less than the rent exempt balance (at the time of this writing 0.00089088 SOL) it will simply fail, as any account needs to end up with either 0 or sufficient balance to be rent exempt after each transaction. You can find the current rent exempt amount an account that doesn't store any extra data needs using solana rent 0 with the cli.
If you send more than that, the transaction will be successful and the account will be credited with however much SOL you sent it. No one will be able to withdraw it. (In theory, if a private key for the account you just sent to exists someone could find it, but in practice the chances of this are so astronomically small that it will never, ever, EVER happen.)


thanks a lot,if the address is out of the curve,the transcation will fail?does the create process need call the program.createaccount function?

No, wether the address is on curve or not doesn't matter in this regard. And no, a normal transfer will do what I described already, no need to call createAccount
